# Any existentialist quotes for the acceptance that life is difficult and meaningless, but we must persevere?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, quotes, quotations

I'm looking for a quote that illustrates the difficulty of life but reassures that the difficulty will come to pass as long as we have the willpower. Particularly, maybe something slightly existentialist even? A **light** reference to the meaningless of life wouldn't be all that bad.

But if there are no specific existentialist references that match my criteria, I'm fine with any quote that illustrates my point.

Comment: Your question is off topic but I found a few pages that lists a series of quotes about "hardship" https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/hardship and http://www.wiseoldsayings.com/hardship-quotes/ and for "adversity" http://www.quotegarden.com/adversity.html

Comment: And quotes about [perseverance](https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/perseverance). Sift through them all, you should find a couple of relevant ones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The controversy over SWRs aside, I think this is a fairly well-worded question under the [tag:idiom-requests] tag.

Comment: @Lawrence but the OP is asking for a quotation, presumably by someone famous. Anyway, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Maybe better asked on meta.

Comment: Perhaps the classic existentialist expression of acceptance and perseverance in the face of difficult, meaningless, and endless human effort occurs in the final sentence of Camus's "Myth of Sisyphus": "[We must imagine Sisyphus happy.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kmo5BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT39&dq=%22We+must+imagine+Sisyphus+happy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5mLHv7JbdAhWS458KHc_bAl8Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22We%20must%20imagine%20Sisyphus%20happy%22&f=false)"

Comment: This question does not provide enough information that could be used to isolate a desired quote from among hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is quite what you're looking for, but there's Per Olov Enquist's quote, "One day we shall die. But all the other days we shall be alive."

Answer (score 0):

**where there's life, there's hope**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/where+there%27s+life) idiom

> As long as someone or something has not completely failed or ended, a
>   bad situation still has a chance of getting better.

As in:

2007   Irish Times (Nexis) 1 Dec.    Where there's life, there's hope... We don't want to think about the dark side.

Answer (score 0):

"Ever tried. Ever failed. No matter. Try Again. Fail again. Fail better." - Samuel Beckett

Answer (score 0):

> Life is hard. It's harder if you're stupid.

The famous existentialist John Wayne