# Idiom meaning "One should not despair ..."

Tags: idiom-requests

I wonder whether there are any idiom(s) meaning "While you know that your ultimate goal is impossible to achieve completely, you should try your best to at least get a glimpse of it because it's enormously valuable".

The nearest things I can imagine are "Getting a glimpse of your goal *is better than nothing*" and "Half a loaf is better than None".

Comment: Related: [Any existentialist quotes for the acceptance that life is difficult and meaningless but ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462483/any-existentialist-quotes-for-the-acceptance-that-life-is-difficult-and-meaningl/462574#462574)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Shoot for the moon - even if you miss, you'll land among the stars.**

This phrase suggests that even a very difficult task can be worth undertaking, as even failure may bring some benefit. The ultimate goal might not be achievable, but trying to achieve it is still worthwhile.

Comment: It seems to be a quote, and so needs attribution.

Answer (score 3):

**It is better to light a single candle than to curse the darkness.**

The meaning is that it is better to do what you can, no matter how little it may seem, than not do anything and just give up.

The [earliest known use](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/better_to_light_a_single_candle_than_to_curse_the_darkness) is in a sermon of W.L. Watkinson, in 1907.

Comment: Isn't there a definite author?

Comment: Somewhat abstruse - not what I would call common.

Comment: Mother Theresa gave us wonderful apothegms that have perhaps not reached idiom status. "I alone cannot change the world, but i can cast a stone across the waters to create many ripples." "If you can't feed a hundred people, then feed just one."

Answer (score 0):

***never say never***

> Do not say that something is impossible, that it will never happen, or that you will never do it, because ***anything is possible***. The term first appeared in Charles Dickens' novel *The Pickwick Papers*.
>
> - A: I'll never be good enough to make the team.
>   B: Never say never. Just keep practicing and see what happens. ([FreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/never+say+never))

There is also ***The sky is the limit!***

> used to say that there are no limits and that anything is possible ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20sky%27s%20the%20limit))

Answer (score -1):

**While/Where there's life, there's hope.**

> 1. So long as one is alive, then there remains the hope of recovery or improvement, regardless of what bad happened in the past.

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/where+there%27s+life+there%27s+hope)].

The hope of improvement, if not ultimate accomplishment ... and you never know.